# What launch market is the new Shetland spaceport targeting?

Tags: launch, launch-site

The new spaceport on Shetland [has now been given planning permission](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-60561379).

It is at quite a high latitude (60 degrees north) which will effect the types of launch that are easily achievable so what is the target market for this facility?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Institution of Engineering and Technology](https://eandt.theiet.org/content/articles/2022/03/shetland-islands-spaceport-ready-for-launch-by-end-of-2022/):

> Three launchpads will be built at the SaxaVord spaceport, allowing for
> the launch of small satellites into either polar or Sun-synchronous
> low-Earth orbits.

[Polar orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_orbit#Usage) have inclinations between 60° and 90° are mainly used for Earth observation, weather and even some telecomms.  Sun-synchronous orbits have an inclination of around 8° from the pole, and pass over the same point at the same time each day.

The BBC article also mentions the possibility of [sub-orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounding_rocket) sounding launches, which are usually used for research purposes

Comment: I don't think sun-synchronous orbits have an inclination of 8 degrees.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep  You're right, I should have written "8 degrees from the pole", I'll correct it, thanks.